# Can I use C++ template in iOS?

Tags: android, iphone, c++, objective-c, ios

I have been using objective-C to develop in iOS.
Now we want to develop an app for iOS and android.
So we want to use C++ which can be supported by both iOS and android.

I know we can use C++ to develop iOS app.
Does iOS support all C++ features (such as template) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iOS SDK uses [clang++](http://clang.llvm.org/) by default (I believe you can still switch back to g++ if you want) for c++ code you will [get features from C++11](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) as well, which gives you a lot of nice stuff such as lambda functions, auto typing, etc. Templates are supported for sure.